# Get file data from REST

Tags: file, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I am trying to find a way to combine two rest calls so that it gives me the correct files as well as the relevant data.

This call gives me the correct data

```
/_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/Items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef,Modules
```

This call gives me the correct files

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages/Landing%20Pages')/Files
```

Is there a way to combine these two so that I get the correct files as well as the correct data for those files?

Answer (score 0):

For that matter you could utilize `$expand` query option which returns *projected fields* (in your case `file` associated with `list item`).

The following example demonstrates how to return list item properties along with a file properties:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$select=ID,Title,Modules,FileRef,File&$expand=File
```

**Update**

The following query demonstrates how to retrieve files in a specific folder with associated list items:

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages/Landing%20Pages')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Comment: How can I incorporate this solution if I only wanted the files in a specific folder within the pages list such as 'Pages/Landing%20Pages'?